# Resizing column - maintain same size images

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `<div>` which shows images, and spans the width of the screen. Images are shown in `col-xs-3` columns.

I need to resize that holding div on an event, which will go thin (`col-xs-3`). But the internal `col-xs-3` need to change to `col-xs-12`. So basically, in 'big' form, I have 4 columns of images, but when it resizes, it needs to have only one column. (Or else the images go too small).

Is there a better way of doing this than trying to change classes? All I want, really, is a list of images, in 4 columns when the div is large, and that must change to the same size images, but in a single column when the div resizes on an event.

I'm wondering if using ul/li and css is possible?

To get an idea... this is what I am doing, but there are images in the green box, that need to maintain their size, and just flow under each other.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/mmfansler/9F62B/

Comment: why not use col-lg-3 and col-xs-12 classes?

Comment: Thanks. I'm unsure how this would work. Can you explain? Sounds promising.

Comment: regarding bootstrap, plain use of  `col-lg-3` and `col-xs-12` won't work due to resize parent div, because relative width of `col-*` has bound to viewport dimension. So even if parent div will narrowed down,say, to 700px, the viewport width  left the same, say 1280px, thus `col-xs` won't switch on. Therefore one of solutions is to use resizable iframe. The other one,  not so flexible, is to leave 4 cells `col-lg-3` which will wrap to next line due to parent becomes narrow. Third variant is - when parent width decreases you can remove class `col-lg-3` at all and assign `width: 100%` to children

Comment: You use bootstrap 2 in your fiddle. Look at my solution with bootstrap 3 (switching classes): http://fiddle.jshell.net/r0jk24m9/1/ . The fiddle requires some explain. I'll give it to you on demand.

Comment: in previous post I was not quite clear saying "relative width of col-* has bound to viewport dimension" - I mean that width of column is calculating against @media query and its value in % depends on viewport width

Comment: @Banzay, you are right... Just using col-xs-12 and col-lg-3 classes would not work. I thought he ment that is triggered on window resize (in that case it would work) but when viewportwidth stays in the lg range that does not work.
what could work is just "swaping those 2 classes"
e.g. selecting col-lg-3 divs (limited to a container div) and calling removeClass("col-xx-3").addClass("coll-xx-12")
or if it is just one trigger to make it smaller and bigger then toggleClass()